# How to print unmatched parameters in Drools

Tags: java, drools

In the following Drools file, I join two queries in the when expression, and print matched results.

```
import com.demo.drools.*;

rule "demo"
    when
        $book: BlockTrade()
        $buys : Trade(type=="buy") from $book.trades
        $sells : Trade(type=="sell", $buys.id==id, 
                                     $buys.price==price, 
                                     $buys.trader==trader) from $book.trades
    then
        System.out.println("buys:  " + $buys);
        System.out.println("sells: " + $sells);
    end
```

It works okay, but I want to log all unmatched trades with an unmatch reason.

For example:

> Trade id=1 doesn't match because $buys.type="both" doesn't match any trades in $buys or $sells

// or

> Trade id=2 doesn't match because $buys.price=50, and $buys.trader="John" doesn't match any $sells

How can it be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593723/where-can-i-see-if-a-pattern-failed-in-rule). If you want to log the unmatched trades, you will need to create the rules for that.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks, your comment was helpful.